# jQuery caching persist to session only

Tags: jquery

I wanted to cache a response from jQuery AJAX calls for many months unless it changes on server. I look at the jQuery source and they just keep a list of eTags in memory and sweep away once you reload the page!

Don't they should cache it in browser and ifModified property is set to TRUE for ajax call?

Or there something I am missing.

Please advise.

Comment: If you want to store something for that long, you may want to use **HTML5 local storage**, which you can easily read up about. (it's not hard to use) :)

Comment: not really what jquery should do, the browser should cache the response depending on what headers you send back .... if you want to store information actively in the browser you can use as Hamza mentioned the HTM5 local storage

Comment: JS variables should have a lifetime of seconds, or minutes at most. If you need something to last months on the client side, use `localStorage` or a serialised cookie. Failing that, store it server side in a database, keyed to the specific user.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I see that jQuery tries to send cache headers with request from local cached object. If they really care they should cache it how browser itself caches response based on upon the cached response header! This is really partial implementation of XHR from jQuery.

Comment: I do want to cache them for a long time however I want to revalidate the cached content on search load and if server returns 303 - Not Modified status it should use from cache else should update returned content. Is that something a local storage could offer? I never used local storage so far